# Tweet button and infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter, google-maps-api-3

I want to integrate Tweet button into a Google Maps v3 infoWindow (infoBox), with I have no success. Of course the script I use works on a simple page. I set up the twitter's js in my template file, added anchor to the html variable in the gmaps javascript file:
...
    Tweet
...

What now can be see is only the "Tweet" text if I hover over the anchor link, and no Tweet grapic button is visible. If I click on this button, Twitter site loads but shares nothing.

With Facebook Like button I had to implement a line of code, whet the "domready" event runs.

How to do it Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem but am getting closer to solving it.

I'm guessing you're using the standard [Twitter examples](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button#Examples) where you add an `<a>` tag like:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" 
data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
```

And then need to get their JavaScript to load:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

So the problem is likely that the infoWindow isn't getting attached to the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

The [Google Maps V3 API InfoWindow Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) has an Event "domready".

So if you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) like I am then you need to do something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(bubble, 'domready', function(event) {
        !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
});
```

Bearing in mind that I haven't got this to work yet :)

Let's sort this sucker out!

Comment: One thing, I set the data-url property, but no url appears in the shared tweet. hmm..

Comment: So I hardcoded part of a link and added the ID as variable so: + ID +
no its
 fully working

Comment: Yes my code is complicated but the base and solution is here: http://hastebin.com/pesawenuxi.js

Answer (score 0):

Just change infobox for whatever is named your InfoWindow object, gyaresu answer is ok, but it will only work once.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infobox, 'domready', function(event) {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
    twttr.widgets.load();
});
```